# ASP.NET Login control not redirecting

Tags: asp.net, authentication, controls

My login control isn't working as intended anymore. It pulls the username and password from a database and then redirects the user to Home.aspx. Redirecting sadly doesn't happen. It does add this to the end of the url, but nothing happens

```
ReturnUrl=%2fHome.aspx
```

This is the shortend ASP code

```
<asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" OnAuthenticate= "ValidateUser" 
DestinationPageUrl="~/Home.aspx"> </asp:Login>
```

Plus .cs code

```
    protected void ValidateUser(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
    {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB_CONNE"].ConnectionString);
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username =@Username and Password=@Password", con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Login1.UserName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Wachtwoord", Login1.Password);
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);

        Session["Uname"] = Login1.UserName;

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
        }
```

I have been working on functionality in which not logged in users cant acces  certain pages, but I'm not sure if that's the thing that's screwing it up..

After fiddling a little I noticed deny users seems to have an effect on it, but don't know any other way to be redirecting non-login attempts.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You appear to be storing passwords in plaintext in the database. This is a big security violation - passwords should be stored one-way hashed and salted. It should not be possible to recover the actual password - you should only compare hashed forms of the password to determine their validity.

Comment: You are not properly handling your [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx) objects (SqlConnection in particular). Special care must be taken with these classes to ensure they release unmanaged resources when you're finished using them. Failure to do so can later result in unexplained errors and/or slow performance, and it will be difficult to diagnose. You need to learn how to handle IDisposable now.

Comment: Completely agree, but this is for a small project in which we're learning asp.net. Security sadly isn't something that's been covered yet. So for the simplicity of the project it's just stored in plain text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, in sql command your query have password parameter defined as `@Password` while adding it to the cmd parameters collection you have `@Wachtwoord` instead of the @Password.

Here is the updated code:

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username =@Username and Password=@Password", con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Login1.UserName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Login1.Password);
```

Also, instead of always redirecting to Home.aspx you can get the return url using [FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.getredirecturl(v=vs.110).aspx). So if you try to access some page Protected.aspx without logging in the user will be redirected to `Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=protected.aspx` and after login user will be redirected to Protected.aspx page.

```
  if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl( Login1.UserName, false));
        }
```